# How do I get rid of the rbenv: "command not found" error I keep getting?

Tags: rbenv

I installed rbenv with homebrew on my Mac (running OS X 10.9.5) and in the instructions on the rbenv github page it says:

> Afterwards you'll still need to add eval "$(rbenv init -)" to your
>   profile as stated in the caveats. You'll only ever have to do this
>   once.

I have no idea how to add that. Where is my profile? ...and what caveats are they talking about?

I'm totally confused but I think as soon as I can figure this out I'll be able to move forward with setting up my development environment.

If it matters, when I run echo $PATH I get:

> /usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin

Comment: It's possible that I installed RVM for another project... checking on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profile is `~/.profile`.  You can add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to it by typing `nano ~/.profile` in terminal.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I ended up getting help via the rbenv github issue tracker since I wasn't getting any responses here. So, since my issues are solved I have no way to test your solution.. but I'm sure it works. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome.  All that matters is you got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I always install `rbenv` via homebrew. With the latest homebrew update I saw this rbenv error appear.

Installing the latest homebrew added the following line to my `.bash_profile`:

`eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

However, that line was inserted after the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` call, so rbenv init actually tried to use the rbenv from the old homebrew location (which doesn't exist anymore).

**The solution** for me:

Move the homebrew line **before** the rbenv line in your `.bash_profile` (or .bashrc or whatever your shell has). That way the correct location will be used to find rbenv (and other tools you installed via homebrew).

Answer (score 1):

When you installed with Homebrew, check if `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH` came after rbenv initialization.